# Android layout - two relative layouts with similar properties, but the second one is bigger in a row

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

This has had me stumped for a bit and I can't seem to figure it out.

I am creating a chat interface with side by side relative layouts in a custom adapter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/lefttext" android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="top" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:paddingTop="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/righttext" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:paddingTop="5dip" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, in a layout view everything looks like it would be perfectly fine. But here's a screenshot of what it looks like on my device:

![enter image description here][1]

The layout on the left sizes the height the way I want it to, but the layout on the right has a big space above it.. Here's how I'm setting the cell background and resources

```
            if (wasMine == 0) 
            {
                lt.setText(Message);
                leftLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speechbubblefrom);
                rightLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                rt.setText(""); 

            }
            else if (wasMine == 1)
            {
                rt.setText(Message);
                rightLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speechbubbleto);
                leftLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                lt.setText("");
            }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `layout_alignParentTop` from the right `TextView`. If that isn't it, are your background drawables 9-patches? Have you ensured that your 9-patch is correctly stretched?

Comment: Wow, ended up being the 9-patched image. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. They're powerful, but can lead to head-scratchers if you're not careful.